# I need an audio duplicate finder with 100% accuracy (acoustic fingerprinting?)

Tags: windows, audio, file-management, duplicate-files

I'm in the process of archiving/remixing band files from long ago, when I just started out. My tagging/naming skills were non existent, so Ive got a lot of duplicates.  I've tried myriad "duplicate file finders" but none of them were up to par.  Need an app with acoustic fingerprinting, or something that will give 100 % accuracy.

Searches by file length didn't work (lots of takes during recording with minor variations, nature of the beast) perfect tunes was useless.  CCleaner useless. Myriad apps from [this hydrogen audio thread](https://hydrogenaud.io/index.php?topic=114075.0), some good but none perfect. I'm asking here as I've tried everything else.  I'm willing to try command line stuff, anything really.  (I am a novice at cmd and powershell, but wiling to try anything). Thank y'all.

Edit: duplicate = *audio content/fingerprint identical (complete null in daw) so far every app I've tried has given a 100% similarity score to a whole lot of files that were not identical. Quite a few of the apps don't decode (from flac) or fail to isolate the tags/metadata from the actual audio content.

Edit: I'm on Windows 11 Pro.  No price constraints.

Comment: Welcome Teddy! Interesting question. How do you want to define a duplicate for this question?  Do you want to consider 2 recordings that are *almost* identical to be duplicates or different?  And how would you define *almost* in the previous question?  Also, if you have OS preference(s) or price constraints, please add them to your question/tags. Thanks, and again, welcome!

Comment: Done! Thank you @RockPaperLz- Mask it or Casket

Comment: Are you looking for something to do this automatically? I would assume if two file are not in the same format, they are not IDENTICAL Even in lossless formats like FLAC there is compression, so the only way to check it would be the audio itself. IF identical duration/bit rate/etc you can load into an editor like audacity, invert one of the tracks, play or mix it, and the result should be no wave at all. If not, what is there is the extent of difference. It will be a lot of manual, but likely the only real way. I would start with a master, invert IT, then load the others one by one and test.

Comment: Likewise in this method, you could visually sync track portions if they are not the same duration, and measure parts (like one was a clip of the other) you would see a blank spot in the waveform where the clip came from.

Comment: You're most welcome. BTW, I tagged your question as `windows` because when a community member (that's now you too!) requests software for Windows that does not require functionality of specific Windows version, that is the tag we use.  Just letting you know for your future use. :)

Comment: Yessir @GeneMoody-Action1 , I've null tested a few of them in reaper and found some stragglers that the various apps identified as "identical" .   The only issue I have is the number of files.  (Around 3,700 flac files, encompassing the 11 +years of takes from countless recording sessions and  several daws:  Pro Tools, Cubasis, Samplitude,Sequoia and Reaper.  There are some tracks from the iZ Radar system as well ) I learned recording/mixing on analog consoles + analog tape + cassette portastudios in the late 90s, but when the DAW shift happened, I was in the military. Lots of rookie errors.

Comment: Whew, that will be a lot for manual. I would try to script/pick the low hanging fruit first, maybe script ffmpeg "ffmpeg -loglevel error -i <input file> -map 0 -f hash -" save a collection of hashes and filenames as csv, pop it in excel, and highlight dupes. Past that, having a large development background, if it were me. I would likely graph them just like an editor's waveform, and store them as XY plots in an SQL database. From there write an algorithm to process those where A contains B or B contains A., That would at least ID partial matches for manual analysis. Maybe knock big a chunk out

Comment: BTW, I make no assertion that would not be a VERY long process both to code/debug and then run. With uncertainty as to the overall success rate until thoroughly tested. It is just a theory based on decades of data analysis. IF they project were handed to me as a dev, and I were brainstorming, that is where I would take it first. And to even begin THAT I would have to find some library to allow me to analyse/store the  data or write one. It would be hella fun, but just as expensive in the long run... Good luck!

Comment: I appreciate you sir! I'm going to do just st that!